# Vee-validate : オブジェクト生成後にjsで正規表現のバリデーションルールを追加したい

Tags: vue.js

タイトルの通り、vee-validateを使ってバリデーションルールを追加したいです。
(for example, telphone num should be required && \d{11})

公式ドキュメントみてもやり方がなく、困っています。
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html#validator-fields

正規表現を使う場合、下記のように指定してもシンタックスエラーになってしまいます。

動作する例

```
this.$validator.attach({ name: "tel", rules: "required" });
```

動作しない例

```
this.$validator.attach({ name: "tel", rules: "{ required: true , regex: /\d{11}/ }'" });
```

この部分が`"unexpcted token : "`となります。

```
"{ required: true , regex: /\d{11}/ }'"
```

詳しい方、よろしくお願いします。。

Comment: 英語版へのクロスポスト: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50050515/5989200 (参考: [マルチポストとは何ですか?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)をご覧ください)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.$validator.attach({ name: "tel", rules: "{ required: true , regex: /\\\d{11}/ }" });
```